# How to select an entire database and display all the information

Tags: php, mysql, database, show, selectall

Is it possible to select all the tables from a database (not knowing their names) and displaying them?
My friend has a mysql server but he doesn't have phpMyAdmin installed and he's begging me to transfer all his php-fusion accounts to his new WordPress blog. He doesn't understand a thing with mysql...
Anyone got an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `SHOW` and `DESCRIBE` statements. That's all phpMyAdmin is doing in the code. Your SQL user *should* have privileges.

List all tables:

```
SHOW tables;
```

List table definition:

```
DESCRIBE table_name;
```

Check out [MySQL](http://mysql.com) for more details.